# Expatriating to Germany without speaking German as a French fluent in English

Tags: germany, working

I am trying to move with my boyfriend to Stuttgart in Germany.

The situation is that I am French, have spent part of my studies in Australia and finished my master's degree in the USA. My current job is in Belgium in a consulting group where some people don't speak the local language (French/Flemmish) but just English.

As I would like to find a job in Stuttgart related to supply chain management, I was wondering how to find a job where it would not be mandatory to speak the local language perfectly since my current level is intermediate in German.

Because as I started looking it up, job titles are in English and offers are in German which makes it hard to apply to anything. Even graduate programs are in German. Would someone have any clues?

Comment: Startups and huge corporations such as Bosch might have jobs where only English is spoken. I have heard of somebody who originally worked for Bosch in another country but later came to Germany for a few years, while still speaking only English. AFAIK her job was mainly to communicate with manufacturers/parts providers from other countries. However, I'm not sure about entry-level jobs/supply chain management though.

Comment: @JIXiang I actually saw they had graduate programs there and just applied :) Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6):

> As I would like to find a job in Stuttgart related to supply chain management, I was wondering how to find a job where it would not be mandatory to speak the local language perfectly since my current level is intermediate in German.

Some insight on the "mandatory" part: I, too, have asked for "excellent written and verbal German skills" in job ads. *Not* because the job needed them. But we have many immigrants and some will isolate themselves by living only in their own communities. They will be with their families and speak their original language, have their own stores and spare time activities. And simply put, some will be stuck with their simple German for the rest of their lives. Because they see no need to improve in their little bubble of "home".

It's super rare that a job actually needs "excellent" skills, but as a potential boss, I don't want to worry if someone can send a simple email without embarrassing the company. That's fine for starters, but it needs to improve, I cannot look over each and every communication for the rest of his or her working life.

So if a job ad says "excellent German skills" and it's not actually about writing poetry, what it *really* means is that we want to see that you can communicate properly. But that's a skill one can *learn*. Even on the job or while already working in the job.

If in the interview you can

- speak some simple German
- explain that your significant other is German and you speak German at home
- explain that you are taking a course in German for business

then in my eyes you are good. You may still not get hired over the native speaker with the same qualifications, but if your qualifications are better, you've got a good chance. Demonstrating that you will *improve* on your *own* is the key.

---

If you really want a job where the project language is English, you need to find large enterprisey corporations. Filter for English skills. If excellent English is required, chances are they can compromise on your German skills.